# Android bitmap.recycle() doesn't work

Tags: android, image, bitmap, stream, recycle

I'm trying to load an image from the gallery, but toSave.recycle() doesn't work.
I mean when toSave.recycle() is called the screen becomes white, the app doesn't crash but the image is not shown. 
Do you have any suggestions?

Here the code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        String imagePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        postImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        saveImage(bitmap);
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Here the method that converts bitmap image and save it in Firebase.

```
public void saveImage(Bitmap toSave){
    if (toSave!=null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        toSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
        toSave.recycle();
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        String imageString = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        simplepostRef.child("image").setValue(imageString);
    }
```

Thank you a lot!

Comment: remove this line *toSave.recycle();* as the same bitmap reference is used to save the image and show in imagefile there is no need to recycle it

Answer (score 2):

**bitmap.recycle()** is working in your case. You just dont need to recycle the bitmap because you are showing this bitmap in a imageview.Have a look at the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()).